# How to make a video file by capturing the animated view in android or java?

Tags: java, android, video-capture

I have made an `imageView` animate from one side to the other side of the screen. Here is the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                handleAnimation(imageView);
            }
        });
    }
    public void handleAnimation(View view) {
        ObjectAnimator animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", 1000f);
        animatorX.setDuration(2000);
        animatorX.start();
    }
}
```

And this is what we see when user clicks on the `ANIMATE` button:
[image]

Now my question is that how I can **make a video file by capturing** the animated `imageView` ?

EDIT:

What I need is: I want to make an app which takes some photos from the user and make some animations on the photos and some effects and also mix them with a desired sound and at the end exports a video clip. And of course if I can I would rather make all these things hidden.

Comment: Hi Hossein, 

I have been trying to do the same, we you able to figure out any solution for the same.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: @ Praveen Pandey  No unfortunately.

Comment: Did you find any solution

Answer (score 6):

You have to record your screen and then crop the video using your view's `xy` coordinates. You can record your screen using the `MediaProject API` on android (5) and above.

```
 private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private MediaProjectionCallback callback;

 MediaProjectionManager projectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(callback, null);
        initRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();


public void initRecorder() {
        path = "/sdcard/Record/video" + ".mp4";
        recId = "capture-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
        File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Record");

            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(MainFragment.bitRate);          
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(MainFragment.DISPLAY_WIDTH,
            MainFragment.DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);
    }


    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
        return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
                MainFragment.DISPLAY_WIDTH, MainFragment.DISPLAY_HEIGHT, MainFragment.screenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null /*Handler*/);
    }

public class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            // mMediaRecorder.reset();
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(callback);
            mMediaProjection = null;
            mMediaRecorder = null;
        }
```

Once done simply call `mMediaProjection.stop()` to finish the recording and save the video as `tmp`
After which you can crop the video at the `xy` coordinates that your view is position using [FFmpeg](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android)

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4
```

Where the options are as follows:

`out_w` is the width of the output rectangle

`out_h` is the height of the output rectangle

`x` and `y` specify the top left corner of the output rectangle

so in your case

```
String cmd ="-i '"+ tmpVideoPath+"' -filter:v "+"'crop="+view.getWidth()+":"+view.getHeight()+":"+view.getX()+":"+view.getY()+"'"+" -c:a copy "+outVideoPath
FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
  // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {}

});
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is not what I need. I want to record a particular layout with its all child views as the same size as device's screen. So this way I can omit the other views.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Why can't you simply change the alpha of those other views

Comment: Or you can change the location where you crop the video from

Comment: What I need is: I want to make an app which takes some photos from the user and make some animations on the photos and some effects and also mix them with a desired sound and at the end exports a video clip. And of course if I can I would rather make all these things hidden.

Comment: You should have mentioned that beforehand. You can create animations from images using `FFmpeg`. As you haven't mentioned what kind of animations you want to create, you can start here https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg

Comment: No, those are `FFmpeg` commands you can execute them in Java using the wrapper I posted in the answer. PS what you're looking for is called a photo montage and not animation. You can Google how to create different types of montages in FFmpeg

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches to archive this.

1- You can acchive this by using the **javacv library (FFmpeg)** to combine a set of bitmaps taken from the view

```
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/sdcard/test.mp4",256,256);
try {
    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setFrameRate(30);
    recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.PIX_FMT_YUV420P10);
    recorder.setVideoBitrate(1200);
    recorder.startUnsafe();
    for (int i=0;i< 5;i++)
    {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        recorder.record(bitmap);
    }
    recorder.stop();
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

all the code of using this library is [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples)

2- You can use this link for record the screen and use as per your need.
[Screen Recorder](https://github.com/vijai1996/screenrecorder)

Comment: Thank you. As I want to capture just the image's animation and not all the views, so I think I should use the first approach. But I don't know how to integrate FFmpeg library into android studio. Would you help me please

Comment: I see that link, but I understand nothing!!

Comment: This won't work well as you are doing everything on the main thread. Your video will appear laggy as the drawing cache isn't drawn every second

Comment: @  Niza Siwale  You are right. Have any idea for solving my problem?

Comment: The problem with screen recording is the app has to be in foreground and the whole animation has to be played. Lets say if you want to download it as video and put the app in background, this might not work, depends on usecase thoe.